# MapView display only squres

Tags: android, google-maps

I have Create application which contains google map.
If i install app with debug mode in device then it shows map fine, but if i installed app after sign in with release mode map is showing only squares...

any suggetions?

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please go throgh this process :

```
      1. Create New Certificate.
      RightClick on Project > Android Tools> Export Signed Application Package.

       2. create new keystore. 
          C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias Fivecondition -keystore d:\Fivecondition

      3.Go to http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html
```

after this use this key and export apk with same certificate .

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new map api key using the signing certificates credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register for a Google Maps key to be used in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this site for Google Maps Android.

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Probably the best site for Google Maps and Android